# How to add headers to web client to support json request

Tags: webclient

I wand to make a Post with webclient in C#, I added this line before the request :

```
var data = new NameValueCollection
            {
                { "UserName", un },
                { "Password", pw },
            };
client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

and got the error :

> The Content-Type header cannot be changed from its default value for
>   this request.

the reason I do it cause I want to get the response in json,